# How to Search Revs in PouchDB Query

Tags: pouchdb, couchdb-mango

Both PouchDB and Mango seem to be missing an option to include previous versions of a document in [an index query](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#query_index).

Such an options might look something like: `include_revs: true`

So, for example, to retrieve a list of all the versions of a user's profile documents in a bucket prior to a specific timestamp, it might look something like this:

```
db.createIndex({
    index: {
         fields: [ 'user_id', 'type', 'timestamp' ],
         ddoc: 'all_versions',
         include_revs: true
    }
}).then(function(){
    db.find({
        selector: {
            user_id: specific_user,
            type: 'profile',
            timestamp: { $lte: specific_timestamp }
        },
        use_index: 'all_versions'
    }).then(function(results){
        // do something with revisions
    })
})
```

This feature seems like it would be very useful for handling merging conflicts as well as any situations where knowledge of the previous state matters. Is there a reason for why it is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Change `include_revs: true` to either `revs:true`, 'revs_info:true`or`open_rev: 'all` to get an array of revs. chechout these answers [Is there a way to get all revisions of a document in PouchDB when using the change feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474864/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-revisions-of-a-document-in-pouchdb-when-using-the-chan)