# Obtaining the list of document revisions in PouchDB when Upsert plugin is used

Tags: pouchdb, revisions

I am building an ElectronJS app and storing a list of documents locally using PouchDB. I am using the pouchdb-upsert for inserting new records. It is also creating revisions in the database and I can see them nicely.

[PouchDB data screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWkAK.png)

Problem is that I cannot fetch a specific revision using [db.get](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#fetch_document) or a batch of them using [db.bulkGet](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#bulk_get) following PouchDB's documentation. In both cases I get a 404 error from the database.

I need to be able to obtain the list of revisions as PouchDB documents so users be able to maintain a history of their documents as they edit them or fork a revision as a new document when needed. Similar to the google docs history feature. How can I obtain the list of revisions created by the upsert plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some options while [fetching a document](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#fetch_document) to get a list of all revisions:

```
db.get(docId, [options], [callback])
...
options.revs: Include revision history of the document.
...
```

Also take a look at this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33478654/3405291).